# Unable to use sbcast to copy over files to compute nodes from master

Tags: slurm, hpc, sbatch, rhel9

I have a cluster of 6 compute nodes and 1 master node for academic research purposes. I am trying to test my cluster and make sure that they can complete an assortment of sbatch jobs submmited. I want to use the sbcast command to copy over a file from master to the compute node, and then eventually execute that copied file.

I am running sbatch test_job, here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=totaltestjob
#SBATCH --output=newoutput.out
#SBATCH --error=error1.txt
#SBATCH --exclusive
#SBATCH --nodes=1


sbcast pscript.py  ~
python3 pscript.py
```

However after submitting the job, the error1.txt file on my compute node reads:

```
sbcast: error: Can't open 'data.txt': No such file or directory.
```

I have tried giving the pscript.py file 777 permissions. I have tried multiple paths for the source and destination parameters, like home/user/pscript.py. Nothing seems to get rid of the error message above. The cluster is up and the nodes are commmunicating with each other, and I have successfully submitted sbatch script without the sbcast command. Open to any suggestions.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the name of the file even in destination e.g

```
sbcast pscript.py  ~/pscript.py
```

Hope it helps